# Openframeworks - rotate an image from its center through OpenGL calls

Tags: c++, opengl, openframeworks

I'm using openframeworks (which renders through OpenGL) and I'm trying to rotate an image from it's center.

I know I should use `ofRotate()` and `ofTranslate()` but I haven't managed to figure it out by myself. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
ofPushMatrix();
ofRotate(ofRandom(10),0.0,0.0,1.0);
leafImg.draw(100,100);
ofPopMatrix();
```

Comment: "i have no idea about Math" You're going to find programming in general to be fairly difficult in that case.

Comment: "i have no idea about Math" You're going to find **graphics** programming to be fairly difficult in that case.

Comment: I need you to read this article carefully http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 9):

Without doing too much math you can use a nested coordinate system offset the image so that when you rotate, you rotate from the centre. In short you'll be doing this:

1. Move the coordinate system to centre of the image
2. Rotate from there
3. Within that coordinate system do one level deeper and translate back by half the image size so you're offset back to '0,0'

In code this would be:

```
ofPushMatrix();
    ofTranslate(leafImg.width/2, leafImg.height/2, 0);//move pivot to centre
    ofRotate(ofGetFrameNum() * .01, 0, 0, 1);//rotate from centre
    ofPushMatrix();
        leafImg.draw(-leafImg.width/2,-leafImg.height/2);//move back by the centre offset
    ofPopMatrix();
ofPopMatrix();
```

I've used the indenting to make it more obvious how the coordinate systems nest.

It's the same as:

```
ofPushMatrix();
    ofTranslate(leafImg.width/2, leafImg.height/2, 0);//move pivot to centre
    ofRotate(ofGetFrameNum() * .01, 0, 0, 1);//rotate from centre
    ofPushMatrix();
        ofTranslate(-leafImg.width/2,-leafImg.height/2,0);//move back by the centre offset
        leafImg.draw(0,0);
    ofPopMatrix();
ofPopMatrix();
```

It's fairly simple to rotate to centre as you can see. In your spare time try to work out how to rotate against an arbitrary point.

Behind the scenes there's a bit of linear algebra going on, but push/pop matrix calls basically handle the nitty gritty matrix multiplications for you. Still you need to understand and practice working with pushMatrix/popMatrix calls. Even though this is for Processing, the principle is exactly the same and the syntax is very similar, so I recommend this article: [2D Transformations](http://processing.org/learning/transform2d/)

Comment: A god amongst men.  +1 helped me.  Just by following your theory.